# Membership price set not updating the right membership years to that of the price chosen when creating membership in civicrm backoffice

Tags: civimember

Steps to Reproduce:

1. From the user's membership page, Click on the Submit Credit Card Membership.
2. Choose the membership and choose the relative price set(having number of terms greater than 1) for the membership and make the payment.
3. For example if a price set option having number of terms as 2 is chosen, the user is only updated to the default Membership Type Duration Unit.

The expected output should be the membership term for (number of terms chosen x Membership Type Duration Unit).

Comment: it could be really helpful to know you can replicate this on eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org or one of the other master demo sites

Comment: I've tried creating a sandbox account in dmaster.demo.civicrm.org few days back but still my account is pending approval by the site administrator.

Comment: you don't need one. the instructions say user = demo and pw = demo

Comment: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=205&selectedChild=summary

Replicated the issue by creating a user with 2 year membership but the result that was added is 1 year.

Comment: https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting

Comment: I added a Price Set on dmaster. options were for 1, 2 or 3 'terms'. i added a back end membership to the admin user for 2 terms, and they got a membership for 2 years. when i went to renew i was not offered the Price Set.

Comment: The terms just multiply the base amount, which makes the other terms prices to be a multiple of the term 1 price. Where in scenarios the term prices are not a multiple of term 1 price, for a two year membership, the amount deducted will be wrong. Could you please provide more insight on this, Thanks.

Comment: i can't paste a screenshot in a comment so will do as an answer (though it won't really help i think)

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of Price Field i thought could be a solution for the front end for you. Not sure if my Comments above were making it clear

[image]

Comment: This works fine in the front end, but when creating a membership in the civicrm backoffice, it's not working as how it should.